# How to configure makefile to overwrite environment variable value exported by a ".zshrc" file?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, zshrc

I am doing deploys from specific machines. These are the same machines
being used for development. This situation can cause some problems
since the environment variables desired for deploys can be different
from the ones to be used for development!

When the engineer is developing, it is useful to have a `.zshrc` file with stuff like:

```
export TFR_RELEASE="my-instance-for-development"
export TFR_DEV="my-instance-for-development"
```

However, the instance for the deployment is a different one!

The project already has a `makefile` to help streamline things. One of
the `make` commands is `make prepare`:

```bash
prepare:
    lein firebase-all $(instance-variables)

    firebase use "$(firebase-name-prefix)$(TFR_RELEASE)"
```

In order to nudge the developer in a good way, I decided to add the first two lines (and comment out the last 2, just for this Stack Overflow question) on `make prepare`. This is supposed to be a "short cut" command preparing the environment for the deployment:

```bash
prepare:
    export TFR_DEV=""
    export TFR_RELEASE=""
    #lein firebase-all $(instance-variables)

    #firebase use "$(firebase-name-prefix)$(TFR_RELEASE)"
```

So, **before** executing `make prepare` I have:

```bash
~/projects/balance on 1524-extend-make-clean-to-erase-TFR-environment-variables
➜  echo $TFR_RELEASE
"my-instance-for-development"


~/projects/balance on 1524-extend-make-clean-to-erase-TFR-environment-variables
➜  echo $TFR_DEV
"my-instance-for-development"

~/projects/balance on 1524-extend-make-clean-to-erase-TFR-environment-variables
➜  make clean
rm -rf .shadow-cljs
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf target
rm -rf public/js
echo "TFR_DEV" "my-instance-for-development"
TFR_DEV my-instance-for-development
echo "TFR_RELEASE" "my-instance-for-development"
TFR_RELEASE my-instance-for-development
```

The result above is expected considering my `.zshrc` file configuration.

Unfortunately, after executing `make prepare` things **do not** work as expected for me:

```bash
~/projects/balance on 1524-extend-make-clean-to-erase-TFR-environment-variables
➜  make prepare
export TFR_DEV=""
export TFR_RELEASE=""
# lein firebase-all
# firebase use "my-instance-for-development"
```

I was expecting to `echo` the environment variables and receive an empty value, but the old value remains!

```bash
~/projects/balance on 1524-extend-make-clean-to-erase-TFR-environment-variables
➜  echo $TFR_DEV
"my-instance-for-development"

~/projects/balance on 1524-extend-make-clean-to-erase-TFR-environment-variables
➜  echo $TFR_RELEASE
"my-instance-for-development
```

I suppose `.zshrc` is **not** properly harmonized with the `makefile`.

Is there a way to configure things so that the makefile *overwrites* `.zshrc` configuration?

Comment: Make can't set environment variables in the shell. The shell is a parent process to make, and you can only set environment variables for child processes.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the hint. Is there an alternative? Would you suggest a work-around to solve the problem?

Comment: A sourced shell script can set environment variables in the shell.